# Wordpress pagination fix or hack when using offset parameter in query?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

How can I skip first post in Wordpress without using the offset parameter (it will break the pagination). Or if there is a a dirty hack around it, I'd love to hear some ides.

I can get the desired results perfectly using the offset parameter when I am querying the posts but it breaks the pagination and I need pagination. I am hoping to basically have a featured post (which will be the most recent post at the top of the page), and then continue you through the query but styling all later posts in a more generic grid. Im having trouble excluding that first post without using offset and breaking the pagination. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us your effort what you did.

Comment: Is your first post just a first post? doesnt matter which post?   Or will a certain post be that special featured post?  IE: a sticky post?    In which case you could fetch the sticky_posts options, and exclude the sticky posts from the query that is doing the other posts using 'post__not_in' https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Comment: Sticky posts also have their own class, so you could use css to style the sticky post differently?